# How to connect Samsung Smart TV to Receiver to Obtain Surround Sound

Tags: audio, hdmi, tv, speakers

I have my Xbox 360, DVD player, and Satellite Receiver all connected via HDMI to my stereos receiver. From the receiver I have one output cable going into the TV via HDMI. The problem I'm having is getting surround sound when using the Smart TV apps, specifically plex. I have set the TV to output using the "External Speakers" instead of "Internal Speakers". I believe this uses "SPDIF", or at least that is the only option available when I have once I switch to External Speakers.

I am unable to switch back to Internal Speakers once I switch to External Speakers and turn on the receiver. Therefore it seems like the TV is aware when the receiver is on and when it is off. I'm wondering how I even know what channel my receiver is suppose to be on, or if the audio is being correctly sent back from my TV.

Could anyone provide me some information on what I am doing wrong, or how I should be doing this?

Comment: *"I believe this uses "SPDIF""* -- You would need an additional connection between the TV and receiver for that to work.  What model of Smart TV?  What make & model of receiver?  *"when using the Smart TV apps, specifically plex"* -- What is *"plex"*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SPDIF is a special optical/TosLink cable (think laser beam through a glass cable).  It's not going to work using HDMI.  You didn't give much info on your receiver.  I have 2 Onkyo RC-360's and they auto-detect everything fine.  You might ask at http://www.avsforum.com/ and find the forum for your reciever, or just post in general.  Also see if there is a firmware update for your receiver.  If you are using Audio Return Channel it requires HDMI 1.4 and a 1.4 compatible cable.  This isn't much of an answer, but it gives you a couple things to look at.
- Joe

Comment: More information on going via HDMI: http://www.hdmi.org/manufacturer/hdmi_1_4/arc.aspx  However I'm not sure if his equipment all supports this.